# when I execute it shws main method not found in class avarage,please define your method

Tags: java

```
public class avarage
{
    public void main(int subjectmarks)
    {
        
        System.out.println("Eneterd subject marks:"+subjectmarks);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest googling the error message

Answer (score 1):

The compiler shows the above error because it cannot find the native main function signature. Just declare the integer `subjectmarks` inside the main function and do not pass it as arguments in the main function, like below for example:

```
public class avarage {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        
      int subjectmarks = <some-value>;

      System.out.println("Eneterd subject marks:"+subjectmarks);
   }
}
```

Comment: The message the OP asks about is an error, not a warning.

Comment: Actually I meant error only, and not a warning. Thanks for pointing out. 'cause a warning usually gets compiled at least.